# Can I convert the one line of also syntax into two lines with Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The Code A is from https://github.com/mycwcgr/camera/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt

It's a little difficult to understand the *also* syntax for me, so I convert the *Code A* to the *Code B*.

I think that the *Code B* is the same as the *Code A*, right?

**Code A**

```
 private fun bindCameraUseCases() {      
       val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also { viewFinder.display.getRealMetrics(it) }
       ...
    }
```

**Code B**

```
 private fun bindCameraUseCases() {      
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
    viewFinder.display.getRealMetrics(metrics)
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is. What the `also { }` extension function does is perform actions defined in its block with the caller object as a parameter and return the caller.

```
val list = mutableListOf<Int>().also { 
    // the newly created empty `MutableList` is a parameter in this lambda 
    // and can be referred using the `it` identifier
    it.add(1) 
}

// is equivalent to
val list = mutableListOf<Int>()
list.add(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, yes: your Code A and Code B do the same thing.  Within the lambda, `it` refers to the object that `also` was called on (the newly-created `DisplayMetrics` instance); and that's also what's returned.

And to answer your implied question: yes, in this case using [`also`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/also.html) probably doesn't have much benefit!

It's more useful in the middle of a complex expression or return value, e.g.:

```
private fun getMetrics()
    = DisplayMetrics().also{ println("Created metrics: $it") }
```

instead of:

```
private fun getMetrics(): DisplayMetrics {
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
    println("Created metrics: $metrics")
    return metrics
}
```

Here it avoids an explicit local value, references to it, and an explicit return; once you're used to the idiom, it's simpler to read as well — especially when it's used for something like logging that's not part of the main program logic.

Kotlin's scoping functions (also, apply, let, run, with) can be a big confusing, but [this page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#also) explains them fairly well.